# XSL 1.0 how to return substring-after with delimiter up to number of length

Tags: substring

I have this XML input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onOTe.png)

I need check where node contains string 'PO' and return value after to 9 characters.

On this case, expected output will be 21456779 which is sub-string after 'PO'.

I'm new to XSL appreciate inputs.  Thanks!

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(substring-after(/HHDVu/THHDVu,'PO'),'',''),')','')"/>
</xsl:template>

Expected output will be 21456779 which is sub-string after 'PO'.